# how I use server without open anything?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script>
function test() {
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
document.cookie = "name=" + name;
console.log(document.cookie);
document.open('chk_name.php','chk_name','width=100, height=100');
} </script>
```

this is chk_name.php

```
<?php
echo "hi! this is chk_name.php";
echo $_COOKIE['name'];
// echo "<script>window.close();</script>";?>
```

I want to check username. I use document.open('chk_name.php');
then I check username in chk_name.php by using cookie. but I have problem when user using their phones.
document.open make a new window. It looks Ok in PC browser. but It looks terrible in phone browser. because they make a full screen. so I want to check username without openning new window. how can I check data using server(db) wihtout openning new window?

Comment: Can you use Ajax on the phone browser? That would open the PHP code in the background.

Comment: Oh thanks!. I'll do it right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use ajax request for this purpose

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "chk_name.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: its 2020 use `const loadDoc = await fetch("chk_name.php", {credentials: 'include'}).text()`